Парсинг 1С файла в объект
Дан txt 1С файл, в котором заданы стандартные ключи и значения.
Как пример:
Кодировка=Windows
Плательщик=Берёзка
...

Читаю построчно файл с помощью StreamReader
using var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\out_belousovd\Desktop\Test4445.txt");
string line = string.Empty;

while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    //....
}   

Есть класс:
public class Parsing1CFile
{
   public string Encoding {get;set;}
   public string Payer {get;set;}
   //...
}

Вопрос в том, как оптимально смаппить читаемые строки в объект класса типа Parsing1CFile.
Писать при чтении каждой строчки кучу if-ов не хотелось бы.
Думал об использовании словаря, где первым значением будет ключ - "Кодировка=", а вторым значение - пустая строка.
Читаемую строку можно разбирать на то, что до знака = (ключ) и после (значение).
По ключу из строки искать в словаре и записывать значение в него.
Но дальше как полученный словарь спарсить в объект - затрудняюсь понять.

Начнем с того, что у вас это по сути словарь, динамический словарь, а значит в него вам и стоит все сохранять, а не в отдельные классы. Далее, почему отдельные классы, когда это у вас по сути "свойства" одного класса? Плодить множество классов под одно свойство... странно. А вот один класс с разными свойствами, вполне. Ну и тут уже механизмы сериализации/десериализации, где через рефлексию вы сопоставляете название свойства (или его атрибута) с названием полученной переменной, если такой есть - задаете значение.

@EvgeniyZ не понял о каком множестве классов вы пишете.
У меня один объект класса, куда надо смаппить данные файла.
Про рефлексию думал (навесить на свойства класса атрибуты с ключами), но это достаточно медленно

Значит я не так понял вашу задумку, ок. Тогда да, как и сказал выше, сопоставляйте названия. "медленно" - я не думаю, что у вас там такие большие объемы данных, чтоб стоило беспокоиться о скорости. Ну а если всеж хотите скорости, то Dictionary<string, string> и прямое его заполнение, без десериазации в класс). Что-то всякие System.Text.Json используют рефлексию и работают шустро, а у вас вдруг "медленно") Если у вас там и правда уйма данных, что рефлексия займет уйму времени, то боюсь вам уже надо использовать базу данных, а не текстовые файлы...

Нужно спарсить файл в словарь, а потом инициализировать свойства:
public class Parsing1CFile {
    public string Encoding;
    public string Payer;
    //...
    public Parsing1CFile(string filename) {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
        var pars = lines
            .Select(s => s.Split('='))
            .ToDictionary(t => t[0], t => t[1]);
        pars.TryGetValue("Кодировка", out Encoding);
        pars.TryGetValue("Плательщик", out Payer);
        //...
    }
}

При желании можно использовать промежуточный JSON:
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp4;

public class Parsing1CFile {
    [JsonPropertyName("Кодировка")]
    public string Encoding { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("Плательщик")]
    public string Payer { get; set; }
    public static Parsing1CFile FromFile(string filename) =>
        JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Parsing1CFile>("{ " +
            string.Join(", ", File.ReadAllLines(filename)
                .Select(s => s.Split('='))
                .Select(s => "\"" + s[0] + "\":\"" + s[1] + "\"")) + " }");
}

internal class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var settings = Parsing1CFile.FromFile("sample.txt");
        Console.WriteLine($"{settings.Encoding} {settings.Payer}");
    }
}

-->

Windows Берёзка

